# add layer move to bottom to stage in kinetic js?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am using Kinetic JS for an image editing & image generating tool. I have 1 issue with the tool.

Here is the link of my tool: http://demo.vthinksolution.com/photodecorator/page2.php?uid=18&cid=4&image=http://demo.vthinksolution.com/photodecorator/img/default.jpg

To understand it a little better, walk through tool.

Right side: Photo frames that when you click on them, the image is framed with the one you chose.

Top: Photo object that you can drag & drop on the photo.

Now the issue I have is:

First we drop 2 or 3 objects on the photo and we can control all the object, but if we select a frame then we are not able to control the object.

I think it's because the frame is set on top , but I want to set the frame on the bottom or just above the image.

Note: Because of the long code, I didn't post it here.

Comment: i don't know why (-1),who ever did it please specify reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

1)

Use Z-index to position the layering of your objects. In this case you would put your main photo/image at the lowest z-index, and then put the photo frame layer or objects at a z-index above your photo/image z-index, but lower than the rest of the objects.

For example:

```
originalPhoto.setZIndex(-2);
photoFrameLayer.setZIndex(-1);
//The rest of the objects should default to z-index: 0 and above.
```

2)

You can add the photo/image to the stage first, and then add the photo frame object/layer second, but set `visible` to `false` for the photo frame object/layer. After that you can add all the other objects and they will appear on top of both the photo and the frame (because you added them to the stage after they were added). When you select a photo frame from the right side, all you have to do is flag `visible` to `true`, and it will appear below your objects, because you added the frame to the stage before all the other objects. The frame was set to be hidden until a frame is chosen. If you choose your white frame (remove frame) then all you have to do is set `visible` back to `false`.

For example:

```
photoFrameLayer = new Kinetic.Image({
  visible: false
})

//OR

photoFrameLayer.setVisible(false);

//And then:

stage.add(originalPhoto);
stage.add(photoFrameLayer);
//stage.add(theOtherObjects);

//When you select a frame:
photoFrameLayer.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: i tried your 1st solution before post question , it not works ,because of z-index photo object on top of the frame but i can't move or scale the photo. now i try for your 2nd solution . thank for help

Comment: i try for second solution , i think about hat but the problem is this is useful for one frame for multiple frame how can i do that. please explain me..

Comment: Did you try adding all the photo frames before your decoration objects? Just add ALL your frames and then setVisible(false) on all of them. Then when you click on a frame, only setVisible(true); for that specific frame.

Comment: thanx to @projeqht -- your explation is help me a lot to solve my problem, setVisibile (true) and not working perfectly . so i use  for hide layer: c.canvas.getElement().style.display = 'none'; and for show layer : c.canvas.getElement().style.display = 'block';

Answer (score 2):

you can also move a shape, group, or layer to the bottom of its container like this:

layer.moveToBottom()